# Let $n$ be an even perfect number greater than $ 6$. Prove that $n \equiv 4 \pmod 6$.

Tags: number-theory, congruences, perfect-numbers

Things I've gotten so far:

Proven that $2^p-1\equiv \pmod 3$ (for some odd prime)

$n$ is in the form $n =( 2^p-1)(2^{p - 1})$ where $(2^p - 1)$ is prime.$ n > 6$, so $p > 2$.

So I have the congruence $2^p-1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$,

and I think I have to prove that $2^p -1 \equiv 4 \pmod 6$ or $-2 \pmod 6$,

but I'm not sure how to accomplish that step.

Comment: You need to use parentheses to force the correct order of operations.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $$x^{ab}-1=(x^a-1)(x^{a(b-1)}+x^{a(b-2)}+\cdots+x^a+1).$$ Hence a number of this form could be prime if and only if $x=2$ and $a=1$ and $b$ is a prime. [Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjcmYDn9PXSAhXj1IMKHejgC_QQFggcMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprimes.utm.edu%2Fnotes%2Fproofs%2FEvenPerfect.html&usg=AFQjCNGRyNBAgAqWBUu2nvKExRAV-bevSA) it has shown that an even perfect number is of the form $2^{p-1}(2^p-1),$ where $2^p-1$ is a prime. Hence we only need to consider about prime powers!!

Consider $p=2$ separately (which gives you the prefect number $6$) and note that all the other primes are odd. Let $p=2m+1.$ Binomial theorem gives us,

$$2^{2m+1}=2(3+1)^m=2(3^m+\cdots+3m+1)=6.3^{m-1}+\cdots+6m+2.$$ Now $n=2^{2m}(2^{2m+1}-1)=2^{2m}(6.3^{m-1}+\cdots+6m+1).$

Hence $n \equiv 2^{2m} \pmod 6$ and you can easily prove that $2^{2m} \equiv 4 \pmod 6$ by mathematical induction.

Comment: In fact this shows that $n \equiv 4\pmod 6$ for any $n\in\Bbb{N}$ of the form $2^{2m}(2^{2m+1}-1)$

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for $n$ is wrong.

It should read $$n=(2^p-1)(2^{p-1})$$.

For example $n=28=(2^3-1)\cdot2^{(3-1)}=7\cdot4=28$

$2^{2k+1}-1\equiv 1\pmod 3$ (from Fermat's Little Theorem), and the power of $2$ forces this to be $4\pmod 6$ (from the Chinese Remainder Theorem).

Comment: $2^{2k+1}-1\equiv 1\pmod 3$  Why can you say this?

Comment: @user3233688, $$2^{2k+1}=4^k\cdot 2\equiv \left((4\bmod 3)^k\cdot 2\bmod 3\right)\pmod 3\equiv 2\pmod 3$$

Comment: $2^2\equiv1\pmod3$ (FLT), so $4^k\equiv1\pmod3$, so $2^{2k+1}\equiv2\pmod3$.